# Where to get all major stock market events/regimes and dates?

Tags: dataset, data

I am looking for a dataset that gets all events and regimes in the stock market (i.e. an event like 9/11 and a regime like Bush's presidency). I was doing some searching and found I could probably do something like that with Factiva, however for reasons I can't disclose, I am not allowed to use Factiva. If you know a website similar to that, please share! I also have many academic databases at my disposal. Too many to name, but if you know of it, I think I may have it.

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question on https://opendata.stackexchange.com/.